# Find column in "DataTruncation" exception

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

Is there any way to find the column name that cause "java.sql.DataTruncation" exception ?
In fact I have great Table with 152 columns so it is not easy to determinate the column that cause this error.
I search in exception stack but unfortunately it does not show the column name.

I am using JAVA 7, Hibernate 3 and MSSQL as database.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

please you can do some thing like this

```
 public static void displayError(DataTruncation dataTruncation) {
    if (dataTruncation != null) {
      System.out.println("Data truncation error: ");
      System.out.println(dataTruncation.getDataSize() + " bytes should have been ");
      if (dataTruncation.getRead()) {
        System.out.println("Read (Error:) ");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Written (Error:) ");
      }
      System.out.println(dataTruncation.getTransferSize()
          + " number of bytes of data actually transferred.");
    }
  }
```

then you can call it for debuging

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

    stmt.executeUpdate("your sql query here");

    displayError(stmt.getWarnings());
```